# Amount Visible Items in LazyRow Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, row, lazy-evaluation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set up amount visible items in LazyRow, for example 1.5 items.
I found LazyListState class which has "layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size" but I can't change this.